# Using Ant Design Variables in Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, gatsby, styled-components

I am using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) in conjunction with [Styled Components](http://styled-components.com) inside of a [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) site.  I would like to be able to access the Ant Design variables (which are written in [Less](http://lesscss.org/)) within a styled component.  Something like this:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: @primary-color
`
```

I did a little research and found two libraries that may be able to help, but I couldn't figure out how to get them to work (at least not in a Gatsby setting).  These are the libraries:

- https://github.com/michaeltaranto/less-vars-to-js
- https://github.com/jean343/styless

The `Styless` package has an example of how to get Less variables to work in Styled Compoments:  https://github.com/jean343/styless/blob/master/examples/Theme.js.

However, I have not been able to get that example to work on my Gatsby site -- whether I try implementing it on my base layout component, in `gatsby-ssr.js`or `gatsby-browser.js`.

So, I am wondering -- is there a way to be able to access Less variables inside of a Styled Component in a GatsbyJS site (either with these libraries or without)?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: You could also simply do: `import 'antd/dist/antd.variable.min.css';` and then use `var()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only looking at getting the Antd variable names in Styled Components, you could instead use the `import` option of `styless`. This is much simpler and there is no need to parse any variables.

In your `.babelrc`, use this code for importing styless.

```
{
    "plugins": [
        [
            "styless",
            {
                "import": "~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less",
                "lessOptions": {
                    "javascriptEnabled": true
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Then, all of the client code can be simplified to:

```
import React from "react"
import { Button } from 'antd';
import styled from "styled-components"
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const StyledButton = styled( Button )`
  background-color: @primary-color;
`;

export default () => {
    return <StyledButton>button</StyledButton>
}
```

Do not forget to delete the `.cache` folder for the effects to take place.

Comment: Btw, can I suggest that you offer to integrate your plugin with Ant Design -- I imagine there are many people who would could benefit from this.  Also, perhaps you could update your documentation on the plugin to include instructions for Gatsby.  Either way, thanks again.

Comment: I am really glad this helped, I do have a similar setup and importing variables this way saves me a lot of work.

You can suggest using this plugin as you wish :)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBergeron How would you go about using less variables in styled-components mixin (i.e. string arguments) ? Thanks.

Comment: @Strebler, you could use the css prop.
For example, `<div css="color: @primary"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Gatsby, you can use loaders, in this case you could get the variable names with `"less-vars-loader!antd/lib/style/themes/default.less"`

This would work fine with simple less sheets without variables, but this does not work quite well for Antd as they set a variable `@primary-color: @blue-6;`.

```
import React from "react"
import { Button } from 'antd';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import DefaultTheme from "less-vars-loader!antd/lib/style/themes/default.less"
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const StyledButton = styled( Button )`
  background-color: @primary-color;
`;

const App = () => (
    <Layout>
        <StyledButton>Hi people</StyledButton>
    </Layout>
);
console.log( "DefaultTheme", DefaultTheme["primary-color"] ); // Here, this shows @blue-6
DefaultTheme["primary-color"] = "blue"; // For demo purpose, setting the value here.

export default () => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={DefaultTheme}><App/></ThemeProvider>
);
```

As promised, I am adding my sample webpack loader to resolve the antd variables. It does resolve about 600 variables, but it still fails with `"JavaScript evaluation error: 'ReferenceError: colorPalette is not defined'"`. This can be useful for projects which do not require `javascriptEnabled`.

```
const less = require( "less" );
const varRgx = /^[@$]/;

module.exports = async source => {
    const resolveVariables = async () => {
        const root = await new Promise( resolve => {
            const parseOpts = {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                paths: ["node_modules/antd/lib/style/themes/"],
            };
            less.parse( source, parseOpts, ( e, root, imports, options ) => {
                if( e ){
                    console.error( `LESSLoader - Error compiling`, e );
                }
                resolve( root );
            } );
        } );
        if( !root ) return;

        const evalEnv = new less.contexts.Eval();
        evalEnv.frames = [root];
        evalEnv.javascriptEnabled = true;

        const ret = {};
        for( let [name, variable] of Object.entries( root.variables() ) ){
            ret[name.replace( varRgx, "" )] = variable.value.eval( evalEnv ).toCSS();
        }
        return ret;
    };

    return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify( await resolveVariables() )};`;
};
```

This can be called with `import DefaultTheme from "./LESSLoader!antd/lib/style/themes/default.less"`.