# To to use antd color variable in custom component styled using css?

Tags: css, reactjs, gulp, less, antd

I'm using antd components in my react project.
I want to use primary color without specifying its rgb or hex value in css of component.
Component which has custom styling looks like this

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: '#0466c8'}}> //here I want to use primary color
</div>
```

I have `dark-theme.less` and `light-theme.less` files where i defined my primary color.

```
@primary-color: #06d6a0;
```

I'm using `react-css-theme-switcher` for switching themes and `Gulp` to compile less files.

Any help/suggestions appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can watch on this post : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470004/using-ant-design-variables-in-styled-components)

Comment: Yes..got the answer. Thanks