# How to use Antd theme variables in emotion

Tags: reactjs, next.js, less, antd, emotion

I am using Antd together with emotion inside of a Next.js site. I would like to be able to access the Antd theme variables (which are written in Less) within a component. Something like this:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: @primary-color
`
```

Did some research and found this question [Using Ant Design Variables in Styled Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470004/using-ant-design-variables-in-styled-components/59472390#59472390) but it is not working for me. Moreover styless is now deprecated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference using `var(--primary-color)` or just `theme['primary-color']`.

The [antd-theme-vars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme-vars) package will help you to generate everything.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way where i am passing antd theme token to emotion theme so that it will be synced with antd all things and changes

```js
const WithEmotionTheme = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const { token: antTheme } = theme.useToken();
  return (
    <EmotionThemeProvider theme={antTheme}>{children}</EmotionThemeProvider>
  );
};

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        components: {
          Layout: {
            headerHeight: 44,
          },
        },
      }}
    >
      <WithEmotionTheme>{children}</WithEmotionTheme>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};
```

Usage

```js
export const StyledHeader = styled(Layout.Header)`
  .brand-logo {
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colorBgBase};
  }
`;
```

ts types will throw error i am figuring that out
basically this should be something from we need to extend the antd theme with types

https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme